# Node, RabbitMQ, and Express

Tags: node.js, rest, express, rabbitmq

I've just started learning about RabbitMQ. I'm building an application with a song queue, the queuing part is what got me looking into  RabbitMQ. I'm using Node and Express for a RESTful API. What I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around is if I can use RabbitMQ for both sides of the transaction. The browser request for a resource goes to RabbbitMQ which goes into a queue. Then Express checks that queue for requests and answers. Is this possible, practical, best-practice, or not meant to be? I found an article with half of the solution, but since it was only half (POST) I am not sure if the other half is feasable.

[node-amqp + rabbitMQ how to convert post request into message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536626/node-amqp-rabbitmq-how-to-convert-post-request-into-message)

Update: I continued my search and found an article that seems to explain how to do this. http://blog.appfog.com/tutorial-rabbitmq-node-js-on-appfog/ I will try it out and update again. would still like feedback on ways to implement this, if it's a good way to do it and why or why not.

Update: Finally found a full implementation. http://blog.appfog.com/tutorial-rabbitmq-node-js-on-appfog/ (see, I really do try to find out the answer for myself!).